# HTTP Post headers, received differently from what's being sent

Tags: php, http-headers, http-post

HI I'm tring to send some headers in my PHP script such as

```
$headers[] = "BATCH_TYPE: XML_SINGLE"; 
$headers[] = "VENDOR_ID: 56309";
```

But they are being received as:

Batch-Type
Vendor-ID

..not as they were intended or required - which is causing me problems.

Anyone know why or how to sort?

Thanks,

```
<?php

function httpsPost($Url, $xml_data, $headers)
{
   // Initialisation
   $ch=curl_init();
   // Set parameters
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
   // Return a variable instead of posting it directly
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"username:password");

   // Activate the POST method
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1) ;
   // Request
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 999);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

   // execute the connexion
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Close it
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$request_file = "./post_this.xml"; 
$fh = fopen($request_file, 'r'); 
$xml_data = fread($fh, filesize($request_file));

fclose($fh);    

$url = 'http://www.xhaus.com/headers';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Expect:";
$headers[] = "Accept: text/xml";

$headers[] = "BATCH_TYPE: XML_SINGLE"; 
$headers[] = "BATCH_COUNT: 1";
$headers[] = "VENDOR_ID: 54367";


$Response = httpsPost($url, $xml_data, $headers);

echo $Response;

?>
```

Comment: How are you acutally sending the headers? With the header() command? At the moment you are just adding headers to an array, nothing else.

Show us that code, and we can help :)

Comment: If you change $xml_data ="TEST"; then it'll work you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of battling with the company of this external server, they were in fact giving me the wrong headers - D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking these headers ? I've just tried myself with the following code:-

```
<?php

header("BATCH_TYPE: XML_SINGLE");
```

And got back the following:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2009 08:56:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.1 with Suhosin-Patch
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.1
BATCH_TYPE: XML_SINGLE
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Hi, I've been using the website www.xhaus.com/headers and also the error logs from the external server I'm trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fsockopen()](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) and write/read manually anything you need. I'm not sure if your implementation of CURL or smth. else like proxy doesn't change your headers. If you want to do something good for sure - just do it yourself ;). Actually it's so easy to create HTTP-request and write it to opened socket...

```
$req = "POST $url HTTP/1.0\n";
$headers[] = 'VENDOR_ID: 1234';
$headers[] = 'MY_OTHER_HEADER: xxxxx';
$req .= implode("\n", $headers);
$req .= "\n\n" . $request_body;

$sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
fwrite($sock, $req, strlen($req));

$return = '';
do 
{
    $return .= fread($sock, 512);
} while (!feof($sock));

fclose($sock);
```

Not sure, but it seems to me, that smth. like this has already been done somewhere in PEAR...

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

To this:

```
foreach($headers as $header)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. It would have to be foreach($headers as $header) {   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    }


..but even then only the last element in the array would be sent....